# How to get both wifi's ip and wifi hotspot's ip in android?

Tags: android, wifi

I want to get both wifi's IP and wifi hotspot's IP.

My code :

```
public static String getWifiIp(@NonNull Context context) {
    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService
            (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifimanager == null) {
        return null;
    }
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifimanager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (wifiInfo != null) {
        return intToIp(wifiInfo.getIpAddress());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I get wifi's IP with this code. But, How to get both wifi's IP and wifi hotspot's IP ?

Comment: Which ip's are you talking about? Why would there be two? Not three or four?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it may be helpful.

**For mobile ip:**

```
public static String getMobileIPAddress() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = 
        Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return  addr.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { } // for now eat exceptions
    return "";
}
```

**For wifi ip:**

```
public String getWifiIPAddress() {
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    return  Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
}
```

**Required permissions in manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**Use it as:**

```
String wifiIp = getWifiIPAddress(); 
String mobileIp = getMobileIPAddress();
```

Comment: I want to sent with context like in my question. How can I sent with context.

Comment: Like this `getWifiIp(@NonNull Context context)`

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Kindly clarify your question.